# Testing abstract SettingConverter with mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocks, just-mock

One of my frameworks uses the `ISettingConverter` interface as an abstraction for serialization.

```
public interface ISettingConverter
{
    [NotNull]
    object Deserialize([NotNull] object value, [NotNull] Type targetType);

    [NotNull]
    object Serialize([NotNull] object value);
}
```

It is implemented by the abstract `SettingConverter` class that provides logic that prevents unnecessary calls to actual implementations and that can fallback  to a default target type for serialization (the first type on the list) if the target does not support the type of the value natively. A target can be a database or an app.config or the windows registry (which natively supports more types then just strings).

```
public abstract class SettingConverter : ISettingConverter
{
    private readonly ISet<Type> _supportedTypes;

    private readonly Type _fallbackType;

    protected SettingConverter(IEnumerable<Type> supportedTypes)
    {
        _supportedTypes = new HashSet<Type>(supportedTypes ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(supportedTypes)));
        _fallbackType = supportedTypes.FirstOrDefault() ?? throw new ArgumentException("There must be at least one supprted type.");
    }

    public object Deserialize(object value, Type targetType)
    {
        return
            value.GetType() == targetType 
                ? value 
                : DeserializeCore(value, targetType);
    }

    [NotNull]
    protected abstract object DeserializeCore([NotNull]object value, [NotNull] Type targetType);

    public object Serialize(object value)
    {
        var targetType =
            _supportedTypes.Contains(value.GetType())
                ? value.GetType()
                : _fallbackType;

        return
            value.GetType() == targetType
                ? value
                : SerializeCore(value, targetType);
    }

    [NotNull]
    protected abstract object SerializeCore([NotNull]object value, [NotNull] Type targetType);
}
```

---

To test this base class I wrote a couple of tests using the free version of the `JustMock` framework and the MSTest engine with Visual Studio 2017.

---

The first test makes sure that `DeserializeCore` is not called if the type of the value already has the target type.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Deserialize_ValueHasTargetType_DeserializeCoreNotCalled()
    {
        var settingConverter = Mock.Create<SettingConverter>(Behavior.CallOriginal, (IEnumerable<Type>)new[] { typeof(string) });

        Mock
            .NonPublic
            .Arrange<object>(
                settingConverter, 
                "DeserializeCore", 
                ArgExpr.IsAny<object>(), 
                ArgExpr.IsAny<Type>())
            .OccursNever();

        var result = settingConverter.Deserialize("foo", typeof(string));

        settingConverter.Assert();
        Assert.AreEqual("foo", result);
    }
```

---

Then I have a test to make sure the opposite, this is, `DeserializeCore` must be called if the type of the value is not one of the target types. In this case `int` != `string`.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Deserialize_ValueHasOtherType_DeserializeCoreCalled()
    {
        var settingConverter = Mock.Create<SettingConverter>(Behavior.CallOriginal, (IEnumerable<Type>)new[] { typeof(string) });

        Mock
            .NonPublic
            .Arrange<object>(
                settingConverter, 
                "DeserializeCore", 
                ArgExpr.IsAny<object>(), 
                ArgExpr.IsAny<Type>())
            .OccursOnce();

        settingConverter.Deserialize("foo", typeof(int));

        settingConverter.Assert();
    }
```

---

The other two tests make sure that serialization does what it is supposed to. So the first test verifies that `SerializeCore` is not called because the type of the value alread is the same as one of the types that the target supports.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Serialize_ValueHasSupportedType_SerializeCoreNotCalled()
    {
        var settingConverter = Mock.Create<SettingConverter>(Behavior.CallOriginal, (IEnumerable<Type>)new[] { typeof(string) });

        Mock
            .NonPublic
            .Arrange<object>(
                settingConverter,
                "SerializeCore",
                ArgExpr.IsAny<object>(),
                ArgExpr.IsAny<Type>())
            .OccursNever();

        settingConverter.Serialize("foo");

        settingConverter.Assert();
    }
```

---

The last test verifies that `SerializeCore` is called with a fallback type which in this case is the `string` because `int` is not supported and must be converted first.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Serialize_ValueHasUnsupportedType_SerializeCoreCalledWithFallbackType()
    {
        var settingConverter = Mock.Create<SettingConverter>(Behavior.CallOriginal, (IEnumerable<Type>)new[] { typeof(string) });

        Mock
            .NonPublic
            .Arrange<object>(
                settingConverter,
                "SerializeCore",
                ArgExpr.IsAny<object>(),
                ArgExpr.Matches<Type>(t => t == typeof(string)))
            .OccursOnce();

        settingConverter.Serialize(123);

        settingConverter.Assert();
    }
```

---

I'd like you take a look at these tests and tell me how good or bad they are and what would you improve if anything? Is their purpose and implementation clear? Did I pick the right names for everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Design

I would argue that this base class doesn't add enough state / operations to be a base class. Consider using a mechanism other than inheritance to accomplish boiler-plate fallback serialisation.

---

### Encapsulation

There is some debat whether *private* methods (is *protected* considered private in this context?) should even be tested. I like [Keith Nicolas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122708/unit-testing-private-methods-in-c-sharp) why you shouldn't.

> *The idea of a unit test is to test the unit by its public 'API'.*

---

### Naming Conventions

- You are following [Roy Osherove's](https://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html) naming standards that have format:[UnitOfWork_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior]
- I'm more a fan of the [ShouldDoThis] and [ShouldDoThis_WhenThatOccurs] format. There is a nice [Fluent Should API](https://lostechies.com/erichexter/2013/01/13/shouldlibrary/) available that could aid testing.

As an example:

> ```
> Serialize_ValueHasUnsupportedType_SerializeCoreCalledWithFallbackType
> ```

vs

```
ShouldCallSerializeCoreWithFallbackType_WhenCallingSerializeWithUnsupportedType
```

---

### Unit Test should test one thing

Some of your tests (like `Deserialize_ValueHasTargetType_DeserializeCoreNotCalled`) perform both white-box as black-box tests. [We could argue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235025/why-should-unit-tests-test-only-one-thing) whether these should be split into two separate unit tests; (1) one checking core is not called, and (2) one checking the result it the value specified. If you do decide to keep one unit tests for both assertions, I would change its name to include that the value itself should be returned.

> ```
> // white-box test
> settingConverter.Assert();
>
> // black-box test
> Assert.AreEqual("foo", result);
> ```

Comment: Interesting pionts. I didn't know about white-box testing. I now use the feature-oriented naming convention for test methods like `Can_find_setting_by_provider_type` which I find is the most informative one. I consider the _fluent should-api_ as fluent-overflow ;-]

Comment: of course, _features_ I should have guessed ;-)

Comment: The one-thing-test is very difficult to follow especially in such scenarious as Read/Write or Encrypt/Decrypt when you need to validate that what you have written can also be read and vice-versa.

Comment: I find the one-thing-test an interesting topic for debat. I also tend to combine assertions I think belong together. There is a fine line when to split tests.

Comment: anyway, zombie down!

Comment: I notice you asked a similar question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167333/automatic-equalitycomparert-tests

Comment: ... let me see, I think I can add a couple of new zombies :-P

Comment: Oh, the automatic equality-comparer tests... yeah, this one needs to be rewritten. I have some new code and there was another question about more canonical testing but I have deleted it as this zombie has begun to rot ;-]

Comment: let me have a go at it ..